# Why is it not good to use a waveguide at low frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, frequency, wavelength, waveguide

Which is the physical phenomenon behind this?

Comment: what is the relationship between wavelength and frequency? How does a waveguide need to scale with frequency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 300 MHz, the mouth of the waveguide would be of order ~1 meter across. At 30 MHz, ~10 meters across. At 3 MHz, 100 meters. At 300kHz, 1000 meters. At all of these frequencies, coaxial wires are perfectly adequate for conducting signals- and very cheap compared to the cost of making tubular waveguides with the dimensions listed above.

Comment: But why should the mouth of the waveguide have those dimensions?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo Hint: it needs to fit at least one half-wavelength of the wave in it.

Comment: Maybe for diffraction phenomenon at the mouth?